Calculate percentage of checkboxes
I am working on a report. The client requested that I determine the percentage of accounts that have given consent (a checkbox field). The question is: how should I calculate the percentage of customers with consent for the report? You're welcome in advance!

Add at least one grouping to your report, and then you can add a summary formula for the checkbox: Consent__c:AVG.






Thank you very much @sfdcfox  !!!
